# Setting the dataset for Recyclerview after filter

Tags: java, android

I am filtering my data using onQueryTextChange, the list filters but it still shows the old data set(unfiltered) which results in data from the old list, even though it shows the new filtered list.

Can someone fix my code which will display the right data set after filter, and unfiltered dataset when the a user will clear the search text.

I will explain it better with screenshots.
Before filter [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVfB0.jpg), clicking on a item will toast the text on it.

After Filter [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQQv6.jpg), on click it is supposed to say HDFC BANK, instead it still shows the data from Position 1 from the unfiltered data set.

I was told its because I am using the BankNames List (unfiltered) text at position when clicking, because of which this is happening.

Can someone please fix my logic here, I am unable to figure this out, even though it seems simple, I am new to Android.

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
 {

    List<DataAdapter> DataAdapterClassList;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

     final List<DataAdapter> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;

    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewadapter;

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;

    ArrayList<String> BankNames;

    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    String HTTP_SERVER_URL = "http://hiddenforsecurity.com";

    View ChildView;

    int RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS;

    LinearLayout lyt, icicBtn, hdfcBtn, axisBtn, sbiBtn, pnbBtn, yesBtn;

     private static int firstVisibleInListview;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        DataAdapterClassList = new ArrayList<>();

        BankNames = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);

        lyt = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout1);

        final Intent go = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StateList.class);


        icicBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.icicBtn);
        hdfcBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hdfcBtn);
        axisBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.axisBtn);
        sbiBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sbiBtn);
        pnbBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pnbBtn);
        yesBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yesBtn);

        final Intent i = new Intent(this, StateList.class);


        // JSON data web call function call from here.
        JSON_WEB_CALL();

        //RecyclerView Item click listener code starts from here.
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    return true;
                }

            });

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                ChildView = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                if (ChildView != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {

                    //Getting RecyclerView Clicked item value.
                    RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(ChildView);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, BankNames.get(RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Printing RecyclerView Clicked item clicked value using Toast Message.
                    //i.putExtra("selectedbank", BankNames.get(RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS));
                    //startActivity(i);

                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });

        icicBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                go.putExtra("selectedbank", "ICICI BANK LIMITED");
                startActivity(go);
            }
        });

        axisBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                go.putExtra("selectedbank", "AXIS BANK");
                startActivity(go);
            }
        });

        hdfcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                go.putExtra("selectedbank", "HDFC BANK");
                startActivity(go);
            }
        });

        sbiBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                go.putExtra("selectedbank", "STATE BANK OF INDIA");
                startActivity(go);
            }
        });
        pnbBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                go.putExtra("selectedbank", "PUNJAB NATIONAL BANK");
                startActivity(go);
            }
        });
        yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                go.putExtra("selectedbank", "YES BANK");
                startActivity(go);
            }
        });

    }


    public void JSON_WEB_CALL(){

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(HTTP_SERVER_URL,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            DataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new DataAdapter();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);


                GetDataAdapter2.setBankName(json.getString("BANK"));

                //Adding subject name here to show on click event.
                BankNames.add(json.getString("BANK"));

            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            DataAdapterClassList.add(GetDataAdapter2);

        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(DataAdapterClassList, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);

    }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

         MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
         SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

         searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

         return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


         final List<DataAdapter> filteredModelList = filter(DataAdapterClassList, newText);
         if (filteredModelList.size() > 0) {
             recyclerViewadapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
             return true;
         } else {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return false;
         }

     }

     private List<DataAdapter> filter(List<DataAdapter> models, String query) {
         query = query.toLowerCase();

         final List<DataAdapter> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
         for (DataAdapter model : models) {
             final String text = model.getBankName().toLowerCase();
             if (text.contains(query)) {
                 filteredModelList.add(model);
             }
         }

         recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(filteredModelList, MainActivity.this);
         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
         recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
         recyclerViewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         return filteredModelList;
     }

 }
```

RecyclerviewAdapter.java

```
    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    public DataAdapter dataAdapter;

    List<DataAdapter> dataAdapters;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){

        super();

        this.dataAdapters = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        dataAdapter =  dataAdapters.get(position);

        viewHolder.TextViewName.setText(dataAdapter.getBankName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return dataAdapters.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView TextViewName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            TextViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewCard) ;

        }
    }

    public void setFilter(List<DataAdapter> bankNames) {
        dataAdapters = new ArrayList<>();
        dataAdapters.addAll(bankNames);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: remove  this line **`recyclerViewadapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);`** from your **`onQueryTextChange()`** method

Comment: Tried removing this, it still shows the same

Comment: @pskink, could you please elaborate, I am new to Android

Comment: I am still unable to fix my logic here, and not understanding what I am actually add and remove from my Main activity and recyclerviewadapter

Answer (score 0):

Make global variable for filteredList and take data from that list. The error happened because you are toasting from the full list. Not filteredList

Comment: Tried this, still shows the same toast, from Screenshot 1

Comment: I tried updating onBindViewHolder too, it is not changing anything, I still get the old text.

Comment: it is because, you are toasting form the full arraylist. ie, you are toasting FullList(0) instead of FileteredList(0). Make a global variable for filtered list and toast from that. Mark as answer if you resolved the issue.

Comment: Okay, so what will I be actually Toasting? code perspective.

Comment: Actually toasting from the global variable. Which is set on your first api call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> may this issue that your are Printing Toast of `BankNames.get(RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS)` from your **`Oldlist`** not From the **`filteredModelList`**

Remove this

```
//Getting RecyclerView Clicked item value.
  RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(ChildView);
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, BankNames.get(RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and set Toast in Adapter class

```
viewHolder.TextViewName..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Toast.makeText(context,  dataAdapter.getBankName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why am I getting from the toast?
MainActivity is not a enclosing class?

Comment: Although my ultimate goal is to pass the Bank name to a Intent, the Toast was just simplifying my question in stack over flow.

Comment: beacuse my friend @Fyz **your are Printing Toast of  your Oldlist not From the filteredModelList**

Comment: I understand the situation, and I am unable to fix this, hence asked for help. I tried your above answer, removed the old toast from the Main Activity and added the one you mentioned in my adapter, Studio is throwing a error that "MainActivity is not a enclosing class"

Comment: No, everything is fine with the enclosing brackets, maybe some issue because of the context

Comment: Did this too, Toast does not display, added a log message too, it too didnt display

Comment: @Fyz you whole code is correct i have also same code for filtering recyclerview

Comment: any other suggestion on this?

Comment: Could you please connect me else where, where we can communicate better, I wont take much of your time.

Comment: sent a DM on you FB